# MFC dialog form on the top of all applications

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

Is it possible create MFC form that cold stay on the top of all applications on PC not allowing to do anything else without entering required information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Always-in-front dialogs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593403/always-in-front-dialogs)

Answer (score 0):

Win32 doesn't support system-modal dialogs any more, as far as I'm aware. This is a relic from 16 bit Windows versions.

You can try yourself with a MB_SYSTEMMODAL type MessageBox.

Closest thing would be to utilize a screen-sized window to display a dimmed desktop background while your dialog is shown. This simulates the behaviour of the user account control -- except that you still can switch tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain something similar setting your window on "TopMost". You can do it on property sheet in design mode, or programmatically with this line:

```
SetWindowPos( pWnd->m_hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOMOVE );
```

Hope this will fit your needs.