# C++/MFC: Dialog gets hidden behind other dialog on messagebox call

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, dialog, messagebox

I am using Visual Studio 2013 C++ MFC.
I have created a mainframe and a main dialog. If I open a new smaller dialog and call a messagebox from a button within this dialog, the dialog disappers behind the main dialog. How can I avoid this? I want the dialog to stay on foreground.
I appreciate your answers.

Comment: use `DoModal();` to make modal dialog.

Comment: [Window Features: Owned Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows).

Comment: Doesn't work! It's an MDI application and the tab-dialog (CPropertyPage/CPropertySheet) disappears behind the mainframe window if I call a messagebox from the dialog.

Comment: @somula: Can you get one handle of the newly created dialog what you need to show at top level screen?

Comment: I can create one handle (or access the dialog's member m_hwnd) - but how can I show the dialog always on foreground / top level?

Comment: @ somula Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593403/always-in-front-dialogs

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it doesn't work. It may work on dialog based application, but it doesn't work with my MDI. The dialog always gets hidden behind the mainframe.